# Entity Framework migration in Azure function app with non hardcoded db connction string

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, entity-framework-migrations

I got an Azure function app which works with EF and I want to do a db migration.

The code for the db context has this part:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlServer(Utils.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_ConnectionString"));
```

I'm trying to do the migration locally from the package manager console and then the `"DB_ConnectionString"` is supposed to come from the `local.settings.json` file.

The problem is that when doing a migration, the env var is not read for some reason like the file is not there. In a regular run of the function app from Visual Studio there are no issues and the values from the files are being read.

Also, if I create an `IConfiguration` explicitly in the code and tell it to use the file, it also works. I can't really create an `IConfiguration` in code, since when the function app running in Azure, it reads the env var from its configurations which has different values than those in the `local.settings.json` file.

What can be done to make the migration to be able to read the `local.settings.json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running migrations using the Package Manager Console or the .NET Core CLI, the Azure Functions runtime isn't being used, so local.settings.json isn't automatically read to populate the environment variables.

Before running your migrations, you can set an environment variable in your OS to mimic the behavior in Azure:

Windows: setx DB_ConnectionString "YourLocalConnectionString"
MacOS/Linux: export DB_ConnectionString="YourLocalConnectionString"
Then run the migration command. This way, the Utils.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_ConnectionString") call in your code will pick up the local connection string.

Alternatively, If your Azure Function project has a launchSettings.json, you can set environment variables there. EF Core tools will respect these settings when running migrations.